Nginx returns 426 upgrade required
In my application architecture, when I make a API request from my frontend application, the request first goes to the reverse proxy server(using Nginx-Clojure 0.5.1), which acts as an intermediary, and then it forwards the request to our backend nodeJS server which processes the request and returns the result.
While calling an API from front-end, we are getting the error 426 upgrades require in the browser's network tab. The protocol version chrome browser showing is http/1.1
To fix this issue we tried to modify the nginx configuration to use http2 instead of http/1.1 but still the requests are using http/1.1. When we used curl to hit the backend API from the nginx server it worked without any issue but when the request goes via nginx it does not. Following is my nginx configuration which I am using:
user nginx;
worker_processes auto;
error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;
pid /run/nginx.pid;
include /usr/share/nginx/modules/*.conf; 
events {
    worker_connections 1024;
}
http {
    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log main;
    server {
        listen 443 ss1 http2;
        server_name backendapi.com;
        ssl_certificate "/opt/greencert/greencert.cer"; 
        ss1_certificate_key "/opt/greencert/greencert.key"; 
        root /usr/share/nginx/html;
        include /etc/nginx/default.d/*.conf;
        location /proxyapi/ { 
            proxy_pass https://backendapi.com;
            proxy_huffering off;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_redirect off;
            proxy_ssl_server_name on;
            proxy_ssl_name backendapi.com;
            proxy_ss1_protocols TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3;
        }
    }
}

Can anyone help me to understand what is wrong in my conf file?
I have also explored and found that we need to add proxy_http_version 1.1 in the nginx config, but after this, I am getting 404 in the API response.
